# Deploying dynamically using hot deploy in Jetty

Tags: jetty

I am looking for way to do hot deployment with Jetty 6. In my case I have to do a hot deployment for a jar. Using the configuration how can I specify to hot deploy for a jar file.

It is specified that it will look for changes in context files. So to redeploy should we need to make change to the context file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jetty 6 to hot deploy a webapp, set a context file under jetty.home/contexts that points at it and simply

> $ touch context.xml

Comment: I want to do it for a Jar file, which is not inside webapps folder. In that case is it possible to do it ? Actual requirement is during jar upgrade I want to delete the jar and upload the new one and make server to pick without restarting. But currently the jetty server locks my jar which is in classpath and not allowing to delete it. Is it possible to achieve this using hot deployment ? If so the jar I want to replace or looking for hot deployment is outside the webapps folder, is it possible to use hot deploy for this ?

Comment: no, you need to use a specialized classloader for that sort of scenario.  There are tools out there like jrebel that allow for this sort of seamless class/jar updating, not to mention efforts like osgi to automate it.  A lifetime ago I worked on a bespoke implementation of something like that using an RMI classloader since it could be beaten into a form to perform like that.